# vsftpd настроил как советуют — не работает

Tags: linux, сервер, ftp, vsftpd

- Сервер: *ubuntu server 16.--, installed( apache2 php mysql-server phpmyadmin ubuntu-desktop mc vsftpd )*.
- Ноутбук: *windows 10*.
- Роутер: *TP-Link TL-WR741N*, имеются следующие настройки:

  - Переадресация/Виртуальные серверы:

    - 80/80 - 192.168.0.101,
    - 443/443 - 192.168.0.101;
  - DHCP/Резервирование адресов:
    **mac* - 192.168.0.101.

Проблема: Сделал вроде все по различным статьям которые нашел в сети (не буду перечислять потому как пробовал раз шесть), итог один: не зайти с ноутбука на сервер по FTP, что бы я там в конфигах не писал (в принципе во всех статьях одно и тоже за небольшими исключениями).

Не подключается ни через локальный IP, ни через внешний. Не подключение выражается, через браузер — «не удается получить доступ к сайту», через сетевое окружение — «не удается установить связь с сервером».

Как устроена сеть:

- К роутеру подключен компьютер с ubuntu server при помощи провода, за ним зарезервирован адрес 192.168.0.101.
- Ноутбук подключен через сеть вайфай к этому же роутеру, за ним закрепен адрес 192.168.0.102.

И вводя на ноуте `ftp://192.168.0.101` ничего не происходит. Вводя на компе `ftp://127.0.0.1` все нормально заходит.

Comment: Вы что, пытаетесь зайти на ftp-сервер по HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: @kff нет я пишу в браузере ftp://*ip*/

Comment: А с локалхоста пускает?

Comment: @donRumata да с локалхоста пускает, никаких проблем.

Comment: А с соседнего компа поускает? И я не понял как сеть организована в плане адресов. Дополни вопрос через кнопку "править".

Comment: @donRumata дополнил..

Comment: Похоже, проблема в настрройках сети. 192.168.0.101 - локальный адрес где стоит ftp-сервер. Он пингуется с ноута? (ping 192.168.0.101). Если нет - на сервере введите ifconfig - и проверьте какой адрес на активном интерфейсе.

Comment: `nmap 192.168.0.101` покажет доступный ftp? На роутере точно надо порт под ftp пробросить.

Comment: @federk понгуется как миленький через внешний и внутренний ип, проблема в другом

Comment: @sanmai nmap не видит ftp только apache2

Comment: Значит копать нужно в сторону iptables - скорее всего порт закрыт

Comment: Видят ли друг друга соседние компьютеры? Возможно включена изоляция,если доступ нужен снаружи, то нужно трансляцию портов писать.

Comment: Связисты обычно рекомендуют не крутить сразу две ручки. У вас может быть допущена не одна ошибка, а сразу несколько. Сначала нужно решить задачу того, чтобы ftp был виден в локальной сети -- и тут присоединяюсь к мысли проверить настройки firewall. Потом уже будете пытаться выставлять ftp в интернет, а пока вам эти настройки на роутере совершенно излишни.

Comment: Прямо даже злобный вариант предложу, утрированный до невозможности: что будет, если соединить ноутбук с компьютером кроссоверным кабелем, исключив роутер? Если удалось увидеть нормально -- значит, пора разбираться с тем, что понакрутили из настроек роутера. Если не видится -- разбираться с firewall. Иначе как это: апач видится, пинги идут - а ftp видится только локально.

Comment: У меня на сервере Apache2 на него я захожу спокойно! через внутренний и внешний ip. Для апач у меня переадресация 80 порта на ип сервера внутренний стоит в роутере, когда добавляю 20 21 порт фтп недоступен все равно.

Comment: @AK Вы совершенно правы!!! Именно такую "мелочь" под названием firewall я и упустил! Огромное спасибо за помощь! Напишите ответ приму..

Comment: А, это конкурсный вопрос, не заметил. Отдайте @sanmai - это он первый предположил.

Comment: Ну или поделите на две части.

Comment: Можно один вопрос принять, а другому дать премию. Так будет примерно поровну.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NB: Связисты обычно рекомендуют не крутить сразу две ручки.

У вас может быть допущена не одна ошибка, а сразу несколько. Поэтому поиск неисправностей нужно вести последовательно и исключать проблемы одну за другой.

Раз у вас локально ftp виден - пробуем проверить, видно ли в локальной сети. И только потом уже будем проверять видимость извне, из интернета - правильно ли проброшено на роутере.

Я бы предложил отключить настройки роутера, но поскольку можно их неправильно отключить - то могу предложить самый простой вариант: соедините ноутбук с компьютером кроссоверным кабелем.

Это минимальная сеть на два IP-адреса, роутер не нужен.

Если удалось увидеть нормально -- значит, пора разбираться с тем, что понакрутили из настроек роутера.

Если не видится -- значить, надо разбираться с firewall. Иначе как это: апач видится, пинги идут - а ftp видится только локально.

Answer (score 2):

Если `nmap` не видит FTP сервера, то скорее всего это означает что он закрыт файерволлом. Открыть можно, например, так:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport ftp-data -j ACCEPT
```

Для более постоянного решения изучите настройку `iptables` в вашем дистрибутиве.